# how to fix Cosmos RPC Endpoint CORS Error

Tags: blockchain

I am building a dApp using `@cosmjs`.
I want to make a transaction on the COSMOS chain on my dApp running on the JUNO chain.
When I tried to get the `signingClient`, I got the following running error.

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at http (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53443:12)
    at HttpClient.execute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53471:65)
    at Tendermint34Client.detectVersion (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55135:35)
    at Tendermint34Client.create (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55128:33)
    at Tendermint34Client.connect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55115:33)
    at SigningCosmWasmClient.connectWithSigner (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23403:64)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:127476:51
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:462877:24)
```

[image]

[image]

Here is my code;

```
import { SigningCosmWasmClient } from "@cosmjs/cosmwasm-stargate";
import { GasPrice }from "@cosmjs/stargate";

.....

const config = {
  chainName: "Cosmos Hub",
  chainId: "cosmoshub-4",
  rpcEndpoint: "https://rpc-cosmoshub.whispernode.com",
  restEndpoint: "",
  faucetEndpoint: "",
  addressPrefix: "cosmos",
  microDenom: "uatom",
  coinDecimals: "6",
  gasPrice: "0.025",
}

.....

await window.keplr?.enable(config.chainId);
const offlineSigner= window.getOfflineSigner?.(
  config.chainId
);
const account = await offlineSigner?.getAccounts();
let wasmChainClient = null;
if (offlineSigner) {
  try {
    wasmChainClient = await SigningCosmWasmClient.connectWithSigner(
      config.rpcEndpoint,
      offlineSigner,
      {
        gasPrice: GasPrice.fromString(
          `${config.gasPrice}${config.microDenom}`
        ),
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("wallets", e);
  }
}
const result= {
  account: account?.[0],
  client: wasmChainClient,
};

console.log(result)
```

Is this the problem of `rpc endpoint`?
I have tried other several `rpc endpoints` but all of them failed.
I really don't know why this happens.
I would be very thankful if anyone could help me with solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your browser blocks request with different origin. Your origin is `http://localhost:3000`, and you requested `https://rpc-cosmoshub.keplr.app`. So, your browser blocks the response of the requested origin if there is no `access-control-allow-origin` header in the response. You can learn more here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors).

I have a workaround program that adds necessary headers to a response.
You have to have golang to run it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var hostname string
var port int

func main() {
    // flags declaration using flag package
    flag.StringVar(&hostname, "H", "https://rpc-cosmoshub.keplr.app", "Specify hostname")
    flag.IntVar(&port, "p", 8081, "Specify port")

    flag.Parse() // after declaring flags we
    http.HandleFunc("/", serveCorsProxy)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), nil))
}

// Serve a reverse proxy for a given url
func serveCorsProxy(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    proxyRequest, err := http.NewRequest(req.Method, hostname, req.Body)
    proxyRequest.URL.Path = req.URL.Path
    proxyRequest.URL.RawQuery = req.URL.RawQuery
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("create request error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(proxyRequest)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("proxy request error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    setHeaders(response, &res)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("response read error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    res.WriteHeader(response.StatusCode)
    _, _ = res.Write(body)
}

func setHeaders(src *http.Response, dest *http.ResponseWriter) {
    header := (*dest).Header()
    for name, values := range (*src).Header {
        for _, value := range values {
            header.Set(name, value)
        }
    }
    header.Set("access-control-allow-headers", "Accept,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With")
    header.Set("access-control-allow-methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
    header.Set("access-control-allow-origin", "*")
    header.Set("access-control-expose-headers", "Content-Length,Content-Range")
    header.Set("access-control-max-age", "1728000")
}
```

You have to save it to file `main.go` and run by `go run main.go -H https://rpc-cosmoshub.keplr.app -p 3001`.
After that you can access the RPC on `localhost:3001`